# What is wrong with progress dialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Am using Async Task in my application to get response from web service using restful web service. My code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json_page);
    _mContext = this;

    new JSONParserTask().execute();

}
```

asynctask class

```
    private class JSONParserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ListAdapter >{


    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    //  dialog = new ProgressDialog(_mContext); 
    //  dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    //  dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected ListAdapter doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ListAdapter adapter = null;
        itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Constants.JsonURL);

          if(json == null){

              Log.v(TAG, "----------- null");
              return null;
          }


            try {

                // Getting Array of Items
                items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);       
                 // looping through All items
                for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject itemsObj = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject products = null;
                    products = itemsObj.getJSONObject(TAG_PRODUCT);
                    Log.d(TAG,"product array "+products.toString());

                    JSONArray images = products.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGES);
                    JSONObject imagesObj = images.getJSONObject(0);
                    Log.d(TAG, "......."+ imagesObj.getString(TAG_LINK));

                    String imageUrl = imagesObj.getString(TAG_LINK);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String kind = itemsObj.getString(TAG_KIND);
                    String id = itemsObj.getString(TAG_KID);
                            String selfLink = itemsObj.getString(TAG_SELFLINK);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                         // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_KIND, kind);
                        map.put(TAG_KID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_SELFLINK, selfLink);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                itemsList.add(map);

                }
              /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(_mContext, itemsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_row,
                        new String[] { TAG_KIND,  TAG_SELFLINK }, new int[] {
                                R.id.name, R.id.mobile });



            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ListAdapter adapter) {


            lv.setAdapter(adapter);    

            // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // some action
                }
            });

        //dialog.dismiss();
    }      
   }
```

with this code every thing working fine without using progress dialog. If u found, the code related to progress dialog is commented in above class.
If i uncomment progress dialog code, am not getting any response from server. I have tried with debugging also but never get any idea to remove this error. 
Can some one tell what wrong am doing here.

Comment: Am not getting any exception. just getting response as null and progress dialog getting dismissed.

Comment: error in logcat is  " Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: are you using tabgroup activity?

Comment: @SanketKachhela No am just using a simple activity which having a list view.

Answer (score 1):

ok the reason for that is you are updating you are adapter in your `doInBackground()` method

```
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(_mContext, itemsList,
                    R.layout.list_item_row,
                    new String[] { TAG_KIND,  TAG_SELFLINK }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.mobile });
```

This code is related to the MAIN THREAD and shouldn't be called here in the background thread, remove it from here, and add it to the `onPostExecute()` , just pass an array list from the Background thread and do other UI related stuff in the `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @Anuj Am testing it and will get back to you.

Comment: @Androholic Sure do let us know.

Comment: @Anuj Tried with your suggestion, the progress dialog is showing. after a long time there is no output in emulator view. but at this line dialog.show(); am getting "android.view.windowLeaked: activity has leaked window that was originally added here" exception.

Comment: @Anuj and still am getting same output in logcat, showing "E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException" as an error

Comment: @Androholic window leaked is caused because your `PROGRESS DIALOG` is still shown and your Activity is getting finished somewhere or destroyed due to orientation change, I would suggest to `dismiss` your progress dialog in the `OnDestroy()` of your activity.

Comment: @Anuj Tried with ondestroy too. in that case am getting json response as null.  If i remove the dialog everything working well.

Comment: @Androholic can you post the new code that you are now facing issues in, along with the way your using the progress dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),"", getString(R.string.dialog_wait_message));
            super.onPreExecute();
        }




   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                if(mProgressDialog!=null){
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
           }
}
```

Comment: If i use this code am getting android.view.windowmanagerbadtokenexception:unable to add window -- token null is not for an application exception

Comment: @Androholic you get the context of activity that is not in running state so you get this error. this code work perfectly.

Comment: How can we consider that my activity is not in running state? Because async task means it wont disturb main thread, and at the same time do the background work. but main thread wont stops its state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, rather

```
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),"", getString(R.string.dialog_wait_message));
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ListAdapter doInBackground(Void... arg0){
      //do your stuff here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(mProgressDialog!=null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
       }
}
```

Comment: This one checks specifially if the `progress dialog` is visible or not `mProgressDialog.isShowing()`

Comment: the problem is not with visibility of progress dialog. i want to know why my result(response from server) converting into null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
          @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(m_context);
        pd.setTitle("Authenticating");
        pd.show();

    }
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            //your stuff
           }
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        pd.dismiss();
           }
```

Comment: that is what i wrote in my question. what is the change in this?

Comment: It should work fine. Can you get the line where the nullpointerexception occurs.

Comment: Am not getting any exception. just getting response as null and progress dialog getting dismissed. An ERROR  in logcat is " Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: Also Do ur downloading in or getting data from server in doInBackground(). Update the UI in onPostExecute.